# Cant get javascript to fire on value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

im having issues with a certain section of code.

The value is updated by a qr scanner system, when the value equals or contains the word "Job" i need a JS function to fire

```
<h3>
     <input type="text" id="qr-value"  value="" readonly />
     <button>Reset Scan</button>
</h3>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qr-value').onchange('input', function () {
        if ($('#qr-value').val() == 'hello stephen') {
            alert('Changed!')
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

QR.JS (where qr code is entered into the textbox)

```
   function read(a)
{
    //$("#qr-value").text(a);
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("qr-value");
    TheTextBox.value = a;

}

qrcode.callback = read;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no onchange() - what you are looking for is .on('change', handler).  I loaded your content into a jsfiddle, temporarily removed the "readonly" so that I could test it, and changed the event binding as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qr-value').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#qr-value').val() == 'hello stephen') {
            alert('Changed!')
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/xgjzppdk/

The fact that you're updating the field with a code scanner adds another level of complexity, but you can both update the value and trigger the change event programmatically as follows:

qr.js:

```
function read(a) {
    $("#qr-value").val(a).change();
}

qrcode.callback = read;
```

Fiddle of full example:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/pfrLs0nr/

Note:  The "Test" button simply calls read('hello stephen') to simulate what will happen in the qrcode callback.  The field is back to being readonly.

Comment: i have a qr.js file which puts the information into the textbox (See update)

Comment: Can you share the line in qr.js that edits the textbox?

Comment: var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("qr-value");
    TheTextBox.value = a;

Comment: Assuming jQuery is loaded before qr.js, you should be able to change that line to this:
$('#qr-value').val(a).change();

Comment: thank you @Benjamin Ray :) i think i know what i can do now :) i didn't know the on change() wasn't possible if no user interaction, now i do :) thanks for this :) great answer and explanation :)

Comment: Updated the answer to be more of a complete response to your updated question, particularly with the changes required to qr.js.

Answer (score 0):

The QR scanner (like other scanners) is forcing the value into the field programatically.  As a result the onchange event doesn't fire (just like if you modify the value with JavaScript).

For most swipe card scanners, there is an extra line break added as part of the value scanned causing an "ENTER" to occur triggering form submission.  Is there any chance you can change your QR code values to include a line break at the end?

If not, after load you may need to 'poll' the field for changes to see if it has been modified.